# burn ubuntu to usb flash drive for install to computer

Tags: usb, system-installation

Do i have to use a disc to load ubuntu on to my pc.
Can't i partition it and install a copy? 
Or copy/burn to a usb drive. 
Sorry new to this.

Answer (score 1):

First: Go to Ubuntu's Download page and download the specific version of Ubuntu you need/want.

Second: Search internet for "Unetbootin" and download the version for your current operating system.

Third: Open Unetbootin and move down the page and tick the box for ISO image. From there, browse and select the Ubuntu file you downloaded.

Fourth: Make sure that it shows your USB drive at the bottom. Then start the installer.

Finally: Reboot the computer. Either go into the setup and change the bios to boot from USB first, or use the one time boot menu and select USB drive. When you get to the Ubuntu Live desktop you will see an option to install Ubuntu to your computer. The installer is simple and easy to use.

I recommend searching the Internet first and learn how to properly set up the correct amount of swap space, the correct size "/" partition, and the correct size "/home" partition. If this is your first time, you may want to let Ubuntu do it itself when the option arises. In the future, you will want a separate /home partition. It makes reinstalling a breeze without loosing any of your personal files or configurations.

Cheers!